# why is torch.nn.Sigmoid() behaves different than torch.sigmoid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am building a RL agent using a neural network to aproximate the Q values of the model.
My first implementation was something like this:

```
self.l1 = nn.Linear(model.state_dim, 128)
self.l2 = nn.Linear(128, 256)
self.l3 = nn.Linear(256, 256)
self.l4 = nn.Linear(256, model.action_dim)

def forward(self, x):
     x = self.l1(x)
     x = torch.sigmoid(x)
     x = self.l2(x)
     x = torch.sigmoid(x)
     x = self.l3(x)
     x = torch.sigmoid(x)
     return self.l4(x)
```

I got some output like this over a series of training episodes:
[image: Average Q values (with torch.sigmoid)]

This output made a lot of sense, the Q values should be negative, because the rewards outputted from the model are in the range [-infinity , 0]

Then I was looking the docs of pytorch, and found a much cleaner implementation of this network:

```
self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(model.state_dim, 128),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
            nn.Linear(128, 256),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
            nn.Linear(256, 256),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
            nn.Linear(256, model.action_dim)
        )

def forward(self, x):
     return self.fc(x)
```

[image: Average Q values (with torch.nn.Sequential, and torch.nn.Sigmoid)]

This output made no sense, because Q values should be heading toward a negative number, if its like the Sequential model how I configured it could not produce any negative number in the output layer, but to me, the configurations are exactly the same. I read that the nn.Sequential implementation is much more GPU-capable, but I don't want to sacrifice the model accuracy in favor of the additional performance. Why are the two implementations behaving so differently?

Comment: What version of pytorch are you using? Torch.nn.functional.sigmoid is deprecated as of 1.0.0 so you should be getting a warning using it.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Hi, I am using pytorch 1.3.0, I was getting the warning, but the I changed it, I am now using torch.sigmoid not torch.nn.functional.sigmoid (the deprecated one).

Comment: Did you `seed` both models equivalently and made sure environment's rewards are reproducible as well? If so, try to set GPU to deterministic mode though it shouldn't make that much of a difference. Other than that they should yield pretty similar results and it's unlikely it's due to `torch.nn.Sequential`.

Comment: Hi @SzymonMaszke , the models are exactly the same, only thing that changed was the forward part shown above. The model rewards are using the same logic in both cases, the Q values difference is shown consistently across runs.

Comment: Reinforcing the point already made. Did you initialize the two networks with the same  exact weights (using a seed)? Initialization can make a huge difference.

Comment: Hi, it seem that similar seeding may be a somewhat useful solution, although it did not resolved my problem completely, I think the rest of the variability may be accountable to the nature of this kind of heuristic, thanks for the insight. @SaiBot